# Why does this function never return false from the else part

Tags: javascript

I introduced console.log into the code to be sure if the array and array elements my code is seeing

```js
function testArrayEquality(array1, array2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (typeof array1[i] === "object" && typeof array2[i] ===
      "object") {

      console.log(array1[i], array2[i]);
      testArrayEquality(array1[i], array2[i]);
    } else {
      if (array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
        console.log(array1[1], array2[i]);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}


var array1 = [
  [3, 4],
  [4, 5]
];
var array2 = [
  [3, 4],
  [4, 6]
];

testArrayEquality(array1, array2);
```

Comment: How are you declaring your arrays? Doesn't `var` default to type `object`?

Comment: @lxxtacoxxl No, `var` has nothing to do with types

Comment: It *does* `return false`, you're just not doing anything with that return value.

Comment: Hint: you ignore the result of your recursive `testArrayEquality` call. The `else` is fine.

Comment: Because an array is of type "object"...https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: when i introduce a return statement to the recursive, it stops the main function that called it and sees only the array for which it was called and hence it returns true which is not valid.

Comment: Think about what you're trying to do: You want to return from the "main" function *iif* the recursive call comes back `false`, otherwise you want to continue. Obviously you need an `if` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is, that you have only tested this function with arrays, that are similar on the topmost level. If there is an error in one of the nested arrays, it will return false inside the recursive loop, but "forget" that false, as you are not doing anything with the return from the recursive function call. what you need to do is this:

```
function testArrayEquality(array1,array2) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
        if(typeof array1[i] === "object" && typeof array2[i] === 
        "object") {

              console.log(array1[i], array2[i]);
              recursive = testArrayEquality(array1[i],array2[i]);
              if (recursive === false) {
                  return false;
              }
        }
        else {
            if(array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
            console.log(array1[1],array2[i]);
            return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}


var array1 = [[3,4],[4,5]];
var array2 = [[3,4],[4,6]];

testArrayEquality(array1,array2);
```

This way, if you have to arrays that are dissimilar on a lower level, the error get's passed on to the original function call

Comment: works perfect. i understand what you did and the explanation you gave. I just wasn't using the value from the recursive as you pointed.

Comment: @dammyspencer I'm always glad to be of help :)